# NPM install and private gitlab repo on Windows

Tags: node.js, gitlab

I'm trying to run npm install and I have package.json file with dependencies. One of dependencies is private gitlab repo.
I trying almost everything.
In config I have

```
"web-authenticate": "git+ssh://gitlab@git......#develop"
```

but always I'm getting error:

```
npm WARN `git config --get remote.origin.url` returned wrong result (gitlab@git... .git) fatal: failed to stat '.': No such file or directory
```

This configuration is not running only on Windows machine

Comment: it seems like your remote origin url were wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43774869/2179157